# Django extending the User model in ECommerce application

Tags: python, django

I have a django ecommerce project that works fine till I decided to improve it. User place order and every time they place an order they have to always input their details (name, emil, address etc) , I decided to upgrade the application so if user had registered before no need to enter details again .

orders/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from shop.models import Product
from decimal import Decimal
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator,MaxValueValidator
from coupons.models import Coupons

class order(models.Model):
     first_name     = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     last_name  = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     email      = models.EmailField()
     address    = models.CharField(max_length=250)
     postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     city       = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     created    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     updated    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
     paid       = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     coupon         = models.ForeignKey(Coupons,related_name='orders',on_delete=models.CASCADE ,null=True,blank=True)
     discount   = models.IntegerField(default=0,validators=[MinValueValidator(0),MaxValueValidator(100)])

     class Meta:
          ordering = ('-created',)
          verbose_name = "order"
          verbose_name_plural = "orders"


     def __str__(self):
          return 'Order {}'.format(self.id)

     def get_total_cost(self):
         return sum(item.get_cost() for item in self.items.all())

     def get_total_cost_after_discount(self):
         total_cost =  sum(item.get_cost() for item in self.items.all())
         return total_cost - total_cost * (self.discount / Decimal('100'))

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order       = models.ForeignKey(order,related_name='items',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product     = models.ForeignKey(Product,related_name='order_items',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price       = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
    quantity    = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "OrderItem"
        verbose_name_plural = "OrderItems"

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.id)

    def get_cost(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity
```

I create account app and extended django user so that user can register address so that the user does not have to type it every time when place an order.
accounts/models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,related_name='UserProfiles',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='Saudi Arabia')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15,default='')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
        if kwargs['created']:
            user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

    post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

and rewrite:
orders/models.py

```
class order(models.Model):
     user       = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
     address    = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
     created    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     updated    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
     paid       = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     coupon     = models.ForeignKey(Coupons,related_name='orders',on_delete=models.CASCADE ,null=True,blank=True)
     discount   = models.IntegerField(default=0,validators=[MinValueValidator(0),MaxValueValidator(100)])
```

now my problem is how can I fix the view to show form of user address with information if user entered before or the user fill form with address
views.py

```
 @login_required
def order_create(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save(commit=False)
            if cart.coupon:
                order.coupon = cart.coupon
                order.discount = cart.coupon.discount
            order.save()
            for item in cart:
                OrderItem.objects.create(
                    # user = User.username,
                    order=order,
                    product=item['product'],
                    price=item['price'],
                    quantity=item['quantity'])

            cart.clear()
            context = {
                'order':order,
            }
            return render(request, 'created.html',context)

    else:
        form = OrderCreateForm()
    context = {
        'cart':cart,
        'form':form
    }
    return render(request, 'create.html',context)
```

orders/forms.py

```
from django import forms 
from .models import order

class OrderCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = order
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','email','address','postal_code','city',)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your `OrderCreateForm`, but I'm assuming it has fields that match the ones in `UserProfile`. If so, try changing the view code to pull data from the profile to populate the `initial` data:

```
 @login_required
def order_create(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save(commit=False)
            if cart.coupon:
                order.coupon = cart.coupon
                order.discount = cart.coupon.discount
            order.save()
            for item in cart:
                OrderItem.objects.create(
                    # user = User.username,
                    order=order,
                    product=item['product'],
                    price=item['price'],
                    quantity=item['quantity'])

            cart.clear()
            context = {
                'order':order,
            }
            return render(request, 'created.html',context)

    else:
        if request.user and hasattr(request.user, 'UserProfiles'):
            profile = request.user.UserProfiles
            initial = {
                'first_name', request.user.first_name,
                'last_name', request.user.last_name,
                'email', request.user.email,
                'address': profile.address,
                'city': profile.city
            }
        else:
            initial = {}
        form = OrderCreateForm(initial=initial)
    context = {
        'cart':cart,
        'form':form
    }
    return render(request, 'create.html',context)
```

Comment: my orders/forms.py   from django import forms
from .models import order


class OrderCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = order
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','email','address','postal_code','city',).   How can I rewrite it to use it?

Comment: I edited your question to include the form and updated my answer to match

Comment: Thanks for help , Actually I edit orders/view.py  and  I got error (django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (phone, city, first_name, last_name, country, email) specified for order)  , I think because the fields of order model changed Then I change the (model = order) to (model = UserProfile) in orders/form.py but Now I cann't create an order and I got error (User profile with this User already exists.) even if useris new and not add any profile data yet , and I cann't use the same userprofile for existing user  when create a new order.